# Siebel sorting not working (but it does in database)

Tags: database, sorting, siebel

So I was working on a Siebel change a client requested and had to test whether it worked fine. Since we weren't given permissions to edit certain things from Siebel itself, we had to go directly to the database (some records became read-only).

We have an Applet that listed the user's "Actions" in a view. Prior to modifying data from the database, the sort worked fine. You could enter a record and then it became read-only. I accessed the database and modified the dates for testing and to my surprise, Siebel no longer sorted the list correctly. The database (SQL Server) sorted just fine by date, but Siebel would do the following.

### Date sort (shown in Siebel)

- 10/20/2014
- 10/25/2014
- 10/18/2014
- 10/17/2014
- 10/16/2014
- 10/15/2014

### Date sort (shown in Database)

- 10/25/2014
- 10/20/2014
- 10/18/2014
- 10/17/2014
- 10/16/2014
- 10/15/2014

Not only is this restricted to the applet itself but to what Business Services retrieve. We checked in the applet and BC but could not find any sort specification or any code of the sort that could cause this. It's like the sorting order depending upon that date field is cached in Siebel.

Any ideas on why this could be?

Answer (score 0):

That order doesn't make any sense. I wouldn't blame cache in this case, I'd rather say that Siebel is ordering the data based on another field/column, different from the one that you updated and see in the applet.

You can see what's actually going on by enabling the **SQL spooling**, which will generate a big log with every SQL statement executed. The easiest way to do so is using a dedicated/developer/thick web client. You just have to [add the `/s` parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/PerformTun/PerformTunCustConfig6.html) in your shorcut's command line. For example:

```
"D:\Siebel\Client\bin\siebel.exe /c D:\Siebel\publicsector.cfg /s D:\sql_trace.log"
```

If you don't have access to a dedicated client, you can [enable the spooling on the server](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B40099_02/books/ImpAppsDB2390/ImpAppsDB2390_Maintenance11.html) too. Or, you can monitor the database, if SQL Server provides something similar to the Oracle management console.

Using any of these methods you should be able to determine the exact SELECT that Siebel is running when you access the business component. My guess is that the `ORDER BY` column won't be the one that you updated.

Answer (score 0):

Which Business Component is this ? Is it Action ? Please check the BC User Property "All Mode Sort" for this BC. If it is set to TRUE, it will ignore whatever searchspec you provide an sort by the U1 Index. The U1 index for S_EVT_ACT table (Action) is ACTIVITY_UID, so it will sort on this and not on dates.